# Returning Json data from Orchard Controller using Jquery Ajax

Tags: ajax, orchardcms

I have been trying to get a jquery ajax function to return data from an orchard controller but so far I have not been successful. I have a break point set on the Controller but the code never reaches the controller.
Here is the JQuery function

```
<table id="tblResults" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
       ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (dynamic item in Result)
        {
          <tr>...</tr>
                }
    </tbody>
</table> 
<input id="__requesttoken" type="hidden" value="@Html.AntiForgeryTokenValueOrchard()" />

@using (Script.Foot())
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $(function () {
            $("#tblResults").tablesorter();
            setInterval(update, 20000);
        });
        function update() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetResults", "ResultsController", new { area = "Orchard.App" })',
                data: { token: $("#__requesttoken").val() },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
}
```

And For the ResultsController I just have this

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
public JsonResult GetResults()
{
   var json = DateTime.Now.ToString();
   return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

NOTE: The Ajax call executes just fine however it never hits the break point set at "GetResults" and the http post url I see is "http://localhost:30320/OrchardLocal/"
Also, what I get for the response is the entire HTML Page.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop Controller after Results: "Results", not "ResultsController". Also, you'll need to include the anti-forgery token in that post. Oh, and setInterval is evil.

Comment: Thats for the quick reply. I have it as '@Url.Action("GetResults", "Results", new { area = "Orchard.App" })'. I used 'ResultsController" to explicitly state that was the controller (guess that was misleading). I thought I included the token via data: { token: $("#__requesttoken").val() },
?

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the token. That you are getting the URL of the root is very weird. Is it what you see in view source or what you end up on in the browser when you submit the form? Did you use a network trace and see anything unusual?

Comment: I am viewing the Response Header in the Firebug Console. That's where I see the complete page being returned (in HTML). The URL above is what shows up on the Console with a 200 OK status code. I am not using a form. I just want to get the updated results and display the results in a table. There is no form on the page and wanted to just use Ajax to get the data from the controller (the break point is never hit) and update the table with the ajax response. When I do alert(response), it shows the html of the page instead of the json date string that should be created by the controller.

Comment: Yes you are using a form: when you do POST with ajax, you are posting a form. What do you see in view source in that script in place of the action URL?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Here is the view source. The Url is empty `var ModuleUrl = "";`

Comment: There you go. I have no idea why that would happen but it explains everything that happens after that. Try to replace with an action of some other controller that is known to work and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I got it fixed with your suggestions and all works great now!

Comment: What was it? It may be useful to others.

Comment: The only thing I added besides the suggestions above was a Route.cs file. I am not sure if that was the issue but it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: because the equivalent setTimeout code is not more complex, and a lot easier to debug. Also, if the scheduled task is taking longer than the interval for whatever reason you're in for a world of pain.
http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/05/14/setinterval-is-moderately-evil.aspx